# Fixed point in RSA encryption

Tags: rsa, public-key

Some papers count the number of the fixed points in the RSA encryption algorithm. They're a minimum of 9 and the real number depends on the smoothness of primes $p$ and $q$.

It very unlikely that a *real* plaintext is one among those fixed points.

One of those fixed point message is the message $m=1$, indeed: $1^e \equiv 1 \pmod N$. Other trivial fixed points are $0$ and $N-1$.

Is it possible to exploit the knowledge of a non-trivial fixed point in the RSA (schoolbook) permutation to factor the modulus $N$?

Saying it differently, given a integer $\bar m \not \in \{0, 1, N-1\}$ such that $\bar m^e \equiv \bar m \pmod N$ is possible to recover the factorization of the modulus $N$?

Comment: It appears that _"Rivest-Shamir-Adleman Public Key Cryptosystems do not always Conceal Messages" by Blakely and Borosh (1979)_ was the first to discuss the number of fixed points and it also discusses some of their properties.

Comment: Hmmmm, if $\bar m$ is a square root of $-1$ (possible if $p \equiv q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$) and $e=5$ (so $\bar m^e \equiv m$), then I don't see an immediate way how knowing $\bar m$ allows you to factor...

Comment: paper @SEJPM cited in the comment above states that "It is shown in [1] that anybody who can find 1 of these latter 6 messages can thereby find p, and thus break the cryptosystem.'  and [1] refers to "Bob Blakley and G. R. Blakley, Security of number theoretic public key cryptosystems against random attack, I, II, III. Cryptologia 2(4), 305-321 (1978). 3(l), 29-42 (1979), 3(2), 105-118 (1979)."

Comment: it seems the problem is well known, but usually is referred to with the terms "unconcealed messages". But I cannot find how to factor $N$ from a non trivial unconcealed message.

Comment: @ddddavidee: yes, if someone finds one of the 6 nontrivial fixed points that always exist ($\bar m \equiv \{0, -1, 1\} \pmod p, \bar m \equiv \{0, -1, 1 \} \pmod q$, then it's obvious.  However, my example of a square root of -1 doesn't fall in that category...

Comment: @ddddavidee: because, in that case, the three values $\gcd(\bar m - 1, n), \gcd( \bar m, n), \gcd( \bar m + 1, n)$ will be the three values $1, p, q$ in some order (all 6 orderings are possible, and each one of the 6 nontrivial fixed points will give a different order)